# warning: implicit declaration of function

Tags: c

I'm programming in C and my gcc compiler gives me the following warning in my function call in `mySedondFile.c:`

```
implicit declaration of function 'func'
```

The function prototype is declared in `myfile.h` as:

```
void  func(char*);
```

Function definition is in `myfile.c`

```
void  func(char*x);
```

`mySecondFile.c` contains:

```
#include "myfile.h"

func("Hello");
```

I'm missing why this would complain.

Comment: Could you show the complete contents of these files (reduce them to minimal content that still reproduces the error)? The devil is in the details for something like this.

Comment: Try compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and see if it catches anything else.

Answer (score 7):

That error is emitted because `func` has not been declared at the point at which you call it.

It sounds like your header files aren't quite as you describe. Perhaps there is some conditional code. Maybe you have a header guard that is not working right. Another possibility is that you have got a letter case error and declared the function `Func` but called it with `func`. Very hard to say without seeing the actual files but you need to look for a reason why `func` is not declared in the `mySecondFile.c` translation unit.

To illustrate this a little more clearly, the following code:

```
int main(void)
{
    func("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

results in this warning:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘func’
```

which is exactly as you report.

According to your description, your code includes a header file which declares `func`. The compiler begs to differ with you and it remains for you to work out why `func` is not declared.

Comment: So there was a #ifdef around the function declaration in the .h file that was causing this issue.

Comment: @SS. Those ifdefs can really confuse you!

Comment: @SS: Given that this post has been viewed almost 9,000 times, you really should officially accept David Heffernan's answer.